# Open Document library new form in new page instead of modal dialog

Tags: sharepoint-designer, document-library, sharepoint-addin

I need to do some customization with my new item form in Document Library,
I have a document library, when i click on new item the new item form opens in a modal dialog i need to prevent this from happening as i want it to open in in a new tab or in the same page but not as modal dialog but i want to display on the page completely.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Goto List Settings > Advanced Settings

You will see an radio button

> Launch forms in a dialog?

Click on "NO" and press ok

and you are done.

[Check this link for details](http://sympmarc.com/2010/11/05/disabling-modal-dialogs-for-list-forms-in-sharepoint-2010/)

Comment: I tried... in SP 2013.. by default its selected as NO, but still its opening in dialog box :(

Comment: did you tried omitting &Isdlg=1 from the link that is on 'New Item'  ?

Comment: I tried and there is no &Isdlg on the sharepoint designer page

Comment: what is the link on New Item ?

Comment: I changed it using a CEW, i wrote some javascript to redirect on click :)

Comment: Please update the question with the modifications you have made. Also please list your javascript

Answer (score 1):

I used this Javascript to redirect:

```
<script language="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script> 
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
    function PageOnLoad() {    
        document.getElementById('idHomePageNewDocument-WPQ2').onclick= function() { document.location="http://sp2013/sites/sitecollection/doclibrary/Upload.aspx"; };    
        }
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('PageOnLoad'); 
</script>
```